# Restrict a process to accessing only a specific directory

Tags: permissions, process, access-control

How could I run a process `dostuff` such that it can only access files/folders in the directory `somedir`?

Comment: How secure does it need to be?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`chroot`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) ([manual here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chroot.1.html))

```
chroot yourDirectory yourCommand
```

Comment: Note that this only works if the `yourCommand` executable and all the files it depends on (library, configuration, etc.) are in the chroot. And it only provides security if the user running the program doesn't run any process outside the chroot.