# How to run a process with read-only permissions?

Tags: permissions, python, readonly

I am running a bunch of python3 scripts containing programming assignments. I'd like to run them on a machine such that they are *unable* to modify (add/remove/write-to) the file system.

Is there a way to launch a program such that it only has read access to the system?

```bsh
SOME_COMMAND python script.py
```

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223006/restrict-a-process-to-accessing-only-a-specific-directory) suggested using `chroot`. However that would require that the python executable and all dependencies be under that root directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could run your command in a file system that has been mounted with the read only option.

Something like `mount -o ro /dev/sda1 /media/foobar` will ensure that no program could write to the `/media/foobar' file system. All you would have to do would be to cd /media/foobar and invoke your program there.

Please note that some programs create temporary files, normally in `/tmp` but your python3 application may wish to create files elsewhere.

Another idea would be get something like an SD card that has physical switch on it that turns card in to read only card.

There is also the option of burning our application to a cd room, the acess speed would be slow.